# Convert a csv file into a xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert a csv file into an xlsx so my macro can read the value properly but I don't know how to do it, can you help me please ?

```
Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
Set ExApp = New Excel.Application 
ExApp.Visible = False
Dim MyWb As Workbook
Set MyWb = ExApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="U:\a.csv", ReadOnly:=True

MyWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
ExApp.Quit
```

Here I open my file a.csv but I would like to open it in xlsx without doing nothing, or maybe to convert it after opening I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You just change the type of your file like black magic :(

Two solutions for you :

1. make your macro can read csv directly, is easy to read a file CSV. (recommend)
2. make a macro to open the CSV file and save it as xlsx file and then you can use your macro to read this xlsx file.

Some code to help you

```
    Dim WB As Workbook

    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("\\users\path\Desktop\test.csv")

    WB.SaveAs fileName:="\\users\path\Desktop\test.xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
            ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer ! Thank you for the code but it tells me "Excel Cannot Open the File Because The Extension Is Not Valid", I am on excel 2013 I don't know if that matters

Comment: did you put the right directory of your file CSV ? For example you have a file in desktop then you should replace  `"\\users\path\Desktop\test.csv"` with  `C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test.csv`